# Printing works from Word but not Wordpad

Tags: windows, 64-bit, printer, wordpad

I have a printer attached to the network with a lot of devices able to print to it.  One of my desktops, however, will only print to it in Word 2013 or from Chrome.  Using Notepad, or Wordpad, or Foxit causes nothing to happen.

The desktop having problems is a x64 Windows 7 Ultimate machine.  The printer is a Brother HL-5140.  This is just really strange to me that the printer prints from Word but not Wordpad on the same machine.  What's going on here?

**Edit**
I'm not sure this matters, but Chrome and Word 2013 are 32-bit processes.  Notepad and Wordpad are 64-bit processes.  Why would it successfully print from some processes and not others?  Aren't they all using the same print APIs?

Comment: Any error messages? If you open up the Print Queue, did any message appears? (Often messages on print queues appears in a flash and disappears immediately)

Comment: Nope, no error messages that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens only on one computer, it may be a problem at the specific computer.
Try completly uninstall the printer and install it again.

Comment: It is only that one computer.  I tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling it.  No change.  I can still print when printing from e.g. Word 2013.  But if I try to print from notepad, it simply doesn't print.

Comment: I believe it is obvious, but, do you have the official latest drivers? can you try another printer?

Comment: I have the only drivers still supplied by Brother for this out-of-date printer. :/

Comment: Can you try another printer?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, other printers work fine.